# Is IntentService an implementation of Command Pattern?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, mvp

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

*"In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or trigger an event at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method and values for the method parameters."*

And according to [professor Schmidt's text](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/CommandRevisited.pdf), a command has:

- ***Time-independent execution of application logic.*** The encapsulation of
  application logic allows to queue it and execute it at a different point in
  time.
- ***Context-independent execution of the application logic.*** The separation
  between application logic and context allows to execute the application
  in separate contexts, such as in a different thread or using a different state.
- ***Exchangeability of application logic.*** The separation between application
  logic and context allows to easier exchange the application logic.

If you encapsulate all information into an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html), the [`onHandleIntent`](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) works as an abstract method to the command executor, just like described at [command processor pattern](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs282/PDFs/8-Services-and-IPC-parts-7-8-and-9.pdf) text.

Thus, instead of explicitly implement the executor in order to invoke a command, you simply delegate command execution to the operating system.

So the questions are:

1. Is IntentService the framework implementation for command pattern?
2. In affirmative case, why some Android [MVP implementations](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/07/18/architecting-android-the-evolution/) explicitly implements its own executor instead of using the one provided by the framework?

Comment: Please, write a reasonable analysis instead of just downvote.

Comment: 1. If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck -- odds are good it is a duck. 2. Could be for many reasons, the author : a)  didn't know about the IntentService; b) didn't think the implementation met the project's needs; c) didn't like the implementation; d) was told not to use it by a manager or other deity.

Comment: @dbugger I was hoping that there was some benefit on using it, because many MVP implementations use this approach.

Comment: If it works for your needs -- use it -- that is benefit enough.